# Label placement on a tikzcd "to path" arrow

Tags: tikz-cd

I am using `to path` in order to have a better control of an arrow in a `tikzcd` diagram. However, I am having trouble to placement the label.

With this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[labels=description, column sep=3cm]
  A\arrow["a+b",sloped,rounded corners,
  to path={
    -| ([yshift=-1.5cm,xshift=-.7cm]\tikztostart.west)
    -| ([xshift=.7cm]\tikztotarget.east)\tikztonodes
    -- (\tikztotarget)} ]{r}
  & B \\ C &  D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I get this
[image]

Moving the `\tikztonode` instruction to the first segment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[labels=description, column sep=3cm]
  A\arrow["a+b",sloped,rounded corners,
  to path={
    -| ([yshift=-1.5cm,xshift=-.7cm]\tikztostart.west)\tikztonodes
    -| ([xshift=.7cm]\tikztotarget.east)
    -- (\tikztotarget)} ]{r}
  & B \\ C &  D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I get this

[image]

Finally, in the last segment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[labels=description, column sep=3cm]
  A\arrow["a+b",sloped,rounded corners,
  to path={
    -| ([yshift=-1.5cm,xshift=-.7cm]\tikztostart.west)
    -| ([xshift=.7cm]\tikztotarget.east)
    -- (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes} ]{r}
  & B \\ C &  D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I get this

[image]

How do I make it appear in the long horizontal segment at the bottom?

Comment: I just added a second way using the `pos=0.25` option.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! In any case, I think that what I wanted was your construction. Mine was just a lack of understanding of the meaning of these -- and -|.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### New answer: without changing the construction of the path.

By default, nodes have the option `pos` initialized implicitly. It is enough here to initialize to `[pos=0.25]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[labels=description, column sep=3cm]
  A\arrow["a+b",rounded corners,
  to path={[pos=0.25]
    -| ([yshift=-1.5cm,xshift=-.7cm]\tikztostart.west)
    -| ([xshift=.7cm]\tikztotarget.east)\tikztonodes
    -- (\tikztotarget)} ]{r}
  & B \\ C &  D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

#### Old answer: by modifying the construction of the path.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[labels=description, column sep=3cm]
  A\arrow["a+b",rounded corners,
  to path={
    -| ([yshift=-1.5cm,xshift=-.7cm]\tikztostart.west)
    -- ([yshift=-1.5cm,xshift=.7cm]\tikztotarget.east)\tikztonodes
    |- (\tikztotarget)} ]{r}
  & B \\ C &  D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```